# ReactJS one-liner if else return more than one children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render more than one children inside of one-liner if else statement. I use ReactJS and MUI. How do I return/render more than one element (an icon and a string with text inside of it)?

```js
<Button type="submit">
{isTyping ? "QISALD" : <OpenInNewIcon/> "LİNKƏ KEÇİD ET"}
</Button>
```

*`isTyping` is a state with a boolean value.

Comment: You could always use a fragment `<><OpenInNewIcon/> <p>"LİNKƏ KEÇİD ET" </p></>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fragment like here:

```
<Button type="submit">
{isTyping ? "QISALD" : <><OpenInNewIcon/> "LİNKƏ KEÇİD ET"</>}
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I just needed.